# Is there a way to add OS X entitlements to Apple applications?

Tags: macos, sandbox, osx-mavericks, entitlements

I have an applescript that is ran by Contacts to perform click to dial functionality. Due to the sandboxing of Contacts, this no longer works.

Is there a way to add entitlements to Contacts - or Apple applications in general?

Comment: How is the script achieving this? If with the so called "GUI Scripting" then you'd have to add the script as an app to the Privacy Pane of the Security System Preferences.

Comment: @mahaltertin The applescript is calling `tell application [NAME] activate dial number end tell`. So it is contacts touching my application not the other way around.

Comment: How is the script started? With the script menu? And what is the error you see in Console.app?

Comment: I'm following the AppleScript-Users mailing list at  https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/applescript-users . It is very active and I think you'll find more valuable answers that I can provide.

Comment: I don't think the script has anything to do with the issue. I actually created a Address Book Plugin using Objective-C and have encountered the same issue. The error comes down to the Contacts app being sandboxed and unable to access my external application. If entitlements cannot be set on contacts then I will try and find a way to jerry-rig this even though it is not best practice.